# How to patch file by adding a branch instruction to another address in arm

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm, patching, bin-diffing

I have disassembled two armv7 files in IDA. I am trying to figure out how I can create a patch to change one to another.

The original file has:

```
__text:00017B60 loc_17B60                           ; CODE XREF: sub_17384+5B2j
__text:00017B60                                     ; sub_17384+636j
__text:00017B60                 MOV             R0, #(aImageCheck - 0x17B6C) ;
__text:00017B68                 ADD             R0, PC  ;
__text:00017B6A                 BLX             _warnx
__text:00017B6E                 MOV.W           R11, #0x50
__text:00017B72                 B               loc_17956
```

The modified files has:

```
__text:00017B60 loc_17B60                           ; CODE XREF: sub_17384+5B2j
__text:00017B60                                     ; sub_17384+636j
__text:00017B60                 B               loc_17B16
__text:00017B60 ; End of function sub_17384
__text:00017B60
__text:00017B62 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:00017B62                 STR             R1, [R1,#0xC]
__text:00017B64                 MOVT.W          R0, #0
__text:00017B68                 ADD             R0, PC  ;
__text:00017B6A                 BLX             _warnx
__text:00017B6E                 MOV.W           R11, #0x50
__text:00017B72                 B               loc_17956
```

In essence, we're forcing a branch to another address, instead of continuing.

In IDA, when I go to the byte patch menu, I get the following for the MOV I want to change:

```
4D F6 C9 60 C0 F2 00 00 78 44 10 F0 46 EA 4F F0
```

In the patched file, I get the following for the new Branch:

```
D9 E7 C9 60 C0 F2 00 00 78 44 10 F0 46 EA 4F F0
```

The difference between both is the beginning: `D9 E7`. Does this mean `D9` is the Branch, and `E7` is the `loc_17B16`? How would you translate `loc_17B16` to the byte value?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: same problem i am getting as above in a diff target i want to redirect the BL to some other adddress how to calculate (the target is arm64)please someone explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure this out and it's almost cheating. I have searched internet and found a branch calculator application that will determine what the new bytes will be after you enter current and next instruction. After that, I just enter new bytes in IDA and branch is done.

Comment: Can you give us the url of your branch calculator?
I didn't find it. Thank you,